# Will MIR have remote display capabilities?

Tags: 13.10, mir

X clients can be displayed on any X server over the network. This is convenient when working in a complex environment. There are other technologies that address this area as VNC, SPICE and NX, but will MIR do this natively? Or will MIR comply and optimise with other protocols like SPICE?

Comment: As always in open-source, you could code it yourself :P I don't know what their actual plan is though...

Comment: Well, if I had the competence in display servers to do that, its still rational to know if there already things done in this area. Just enough to dig around.

Comment: If you just want to "ssh -X remote_desktop", using the famous "export DISPLAY" X feature, from within your Ubuntu with MIR (i.e. without X), then, a root-less X.org will run on top of your MIR display, to show your remote app using native X protocol (just like XQuartz does for OSX)...